# Running curl from a Windows server - want to authenticate as the computer

Tags: linux, windows, curl

I need to run a curl command using Kerberos authentication from a Windows 2008 R2 server to a Linux server. I need to be able to authenticate as the computer account instead of my personal account, as this will be called from a script. The Linux admins are telling me they have allowed computers from the domain I am in to their domain (sorry, I am at a loss with this security stuff). 
Has someone done this in the past? I have been struggling and can really use some help! I am trying to even run a simple XGET and get unauthorized.
Thanks!

Comment: *"Kerberos authentication to a Linux server"* meaning which flavor of Kerberos: the Microsoft one (SSPI) or the Java/Linux one (GSSAPI)?

Comment: AFAIK all the Windows versions of CURL available for download are compiled with SSPI, and cannot access a web server using GSSAPI. Just run `curl --version` and check whether you see sthg like `Features: ... SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM ...` or instead `Features: ... GSS-Negotiate NTLM ...`

Comment: By the way, you read the CURL manual and used the appropriate options `--negotiate -u : ` to enable SPNEGO with the default Kerberos ticket *(the one Windows got from Active Directory when you logged in)*, did you??

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by *"the computer account"* - you mean an AD service account created just for you?

Comment: Sorry, all, I missed these comments, I don't have an alert set :( .

Comment: Sorry, all, I missed these comments, I don't have an alert set :( . One of the guys on our Linux team noted that curl on Windows was apparently trying to NTMLSSP as a gss mech instead of kerberos5. He compiled a new curl for me which included something to do with Cygwin and Kerberos 5 and it worked. My end goal is to not have to run kinit manually, as that stops any automated scripts in their tracks. I am now trying to just create a keytab file for my own user id, but that's not working. I just posted that issue today. Thanks all !

Comment: and yes my curl command looks like this - curl -XPUT --negotiate -u : --insecure -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary ... I run this after I have manually run kinit on my workstation.

Comment: Create the keytab on Linux using `ktutil`, with the **exact** encryption that is expected by your KDC (cf. `krb5.conf` if your client conf is up-to-date) then upload it to Windows. Make sure that `kinit` finds its own local `krb5.ini` e.g. `set KRB5_CONFIG=...`  And if the default cache *(which on Windows is a memory-resident process)* does not work, try a FILE:  cache for both `kinit` and `curl` e.g. `set KRB5CCNAME=...`  http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/env_variables.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask the security guy for approval and to create the file.

Comment: My Windows domain is not the same as the Linux domain. I use kinit with my Linux KDC realm id manually. I need to create a keytab file on my Windows server to authenticate to the Linux API I am trying to reach.    I have tried:    ktpass -princ me@WINDOWS.DOMAIN -pass password -out c:\somewhere.keytab -crypto xxx -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL 
Then I try kinit -k -t somewhere.keytab me@WINDOWS.DOMAIN...I get a message Generic preauthentication failure while getting initial credentials. <br/>I know this is simple to some, but not for me, so thanks for your help!

Comment: Forget about the Win domain and your Win user -- it's the Linux realm that you are connecting to. So import your valid Linux `krb5.conf` and keytab to your PC and use them to authenticate against Linux KDC as "linuxuser@LINUX.REALM"